# Is it possible to modify privateFor addreses in a private Smart Contract (Quorum)?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, private-blockchain, quorum

I know how a private smart contract works providing a list of accepted addreses to privateFor property, but what if I want to disable (or enable) any address visibility?

Should I deploy a new Smart Contract? Will the Smart Contract always be visible for the privateFor addresses?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of version 2.2.3 of Quorum, private parties are static -- that means after initial private smart contract creation, you are not able to add or remove parties that are privy to the contents of the smart contract. This is a very desirable feature that we are working on at the moment and we will have a solution for you in the next several month.

That said, our recommendation for the short term, for when you need to extend the party list, is to destroy (or otherwise inactivate) the previous contract and create a new one based on the data set of the previous one.

Comment: Thanks too much, so now I will explore how to do it (inactivate/create new) dinamically.